# Trying to sideload an app which has gone through the Desktop Bridge in Visual Studio

Tags: desktop-bridge

My app works as expected in the development/debugging environment in Visual Studio, and I ultimately want this on the Windows Store, but have been unsuccessful so far.
My app has used the Visual Studio desktop bridge tool for all my code.

I have decided to attempt to sideload my windows 10 app to another windows 10 machine (please confirm if it has to be Windows 10 home with sideloading enabled in the settings should be OK or not).  Again I am so far unsuccessful.

I have followed the steps in visual studio to prepare for the store by creating the app package.  I can see the following files .ps1 .appxbundle .appxsym .cer in the directory.

I believe I have successfully installed the certificate on the destination machine and also run the .ps1 file in the powershell which seems to run successfully.

Can you please help advise me on all the possible reasons you can think of as to why this could be failing to launch.  I can actually see my app in the start menu but when I try to launch it, absolutely nothing happens.

Manifest Dependencies Section:

```
<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" /> 
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" /> 
</Dependencies>
```

I would be grateful for any advice you can give.

Comment: If you get your exe being executed, maybe you need to somehow debug your exe to see if an exception occurs that causes the app to close.

Comment: Please share the dependency section from your appxmanifest.xml file in the package.

Comment: Hi Stefan <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
  </Dependencies>